xdg-open & callto link & google chrome
I have a strange situation. In my company we use Xivo for all our call, so we have xivo-desktop-assistant installed on our desktop. Everything works fine with Firefox, when we click callto or tel link, xivo-desktop is open and compose, but we study to move on chrome alternative.
Every time I want to open a callto or tel link from Google Chrome or other browser based on Chrome, xdg open firefox but not Xivo-desktop.
I try in command line to do xdg-open callto:123 (to call 123) he still open Firefox (if I remove firefox from desktop, xdg try to open other apps but no Xivo-desktop).
So it's look to be a xdg problem.
If I do something like xdg-settings get default-url-scheme-handler callto (same with tel)
the answer is xivo-desktop-assistant.desktop who looks good.
But I don't understand why xdg don't want to work correctly.
All file I check in ~/.local/share/applications, /usr/share/mime, /usr/share/applications looks to be good.
During I make tests for this post, I see if the phone number is 6 or more digit it's working... where I can make this change ? (or internal number are on 3 digit).
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 with KDE
Any idea ?

More information, if I do something like : /opt/xivo-desktop-assistant/xivo-desktop-assistant callto:123 it's working
Thanks for you help
